# GDB Debugging: Application termintes with SIGTRAP

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

Have been trying to remote debug an application running on my target using GDB.
The target is Armv6 based, the OS is linux and the application is a QT based Multithreaded application.

I am able to set the break point. But when the break point is hit, program gets crashed along with SIGTRAP.

Hint: I am able to run another small sample Multithreaded QT-App on the same target.

What could be the problem?

### GDB Log as follows

Breakpoint 1 at 0x4ad52c: file <> , <>. (2 locations)
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)

### (gdb)

Answer (score 7):

You have maybe a solution here:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/FAQ#GDB_does_not_see_any_threads_besides_the_one_in_which_crash_occurred.3B_or_SIGTRAP_kills_my_program_when_I_set_a_breakpoint.

Hope this help.

Regards.

Comment: The page was helpful.. But that wasnt the case here... I partially solved the issue by starting the application with GDB (instead of attaching the process)... Then its working fine.. No idea abt the root cause though..

Answer (score 1):

well, the gdb trace the process by ptrace , and the ptrace set breakpoint in the space of the
thread , the space addr is shared by the other thread, if the other thread reached the breakpoint, oh, the kernel generate a sigtrap for the thread.

more info in the follow
http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/ltrace-devel/2006-April/000036.html